# DJI Android SDK Integration Demo Tutorial Issue

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am following [this](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration) exact tutorial for adding the SDK into a new android project.
However, when i try running the project on my physical device i get the following error:

```
No implementation found for void dji.upgrade.internal.csdk.upgradeadapter.UpgradeAdapterManager.setFirmwareStoreDirectory(java.lang.String)
(tried Java_dji_upgrade_internal_csdk_upgradeadapter_UpgradeAdapterManager_setFirmwareStoreDirectory and Java_dji_upgrade_internal_csdk_upgradeadapter_UpgradeAdapterManager_setFirmwareStoreDirectory__Ljava_lang_String_2)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void dji.upgrade.internal.csdk.upgradeadapter.UpgradeAdapterManager.setFirmwareStoreDirectory(java.lang.String) (tried Java_dji_upgrade_internal_csdk_upgradeadapter_UpgradeAdapterManager_setFirmwareStoreDirectory and Java_dji_upgrade_internal_csdk_upgradeadapter_UpgradeAdapterManager_setFirmwareStoreDirectory__Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at dji.upgrade.internal.csdk.upgradeadapter.UpgradeAdapterManager.setFirmwareStoreDirectory(Native Method)
    at dji.upgrade.internal.csdk.upgradeadapter.UpgradeAdapterManager.e(Unknown Source:12)
    at dji.upgrade.internal.csdk.upgradeadapter.UpgradeAdapterManager.b(Unknown Source:2)
    at dji.upgrade.internal.csdk.CSDKManager.a(Unknown Source:15)
    at dji.upgrade.internal.UpgradeManagerImpl.a(Unknown Source:27)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initParams(Unknown Source:24)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initSDKManager(Unknown Source:253)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.registerApp(Unknown Source:45)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.access$600(Unknown Source:0)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$5$1.onDownloadSuccess(Unknown Source:6)
    at dji.internal.flysafe.DJIFlySafeDBLoader.a(Unknown Source:19)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$5.run(Unknown Source:33)
    at dji.sdksharedlib.util.DJISDKCacheThreadManager$1.run(Unknown Source:5)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is my gradle sample:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.airsmat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
            release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    /**
     * Dji SDK
     */
    implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.11.1')
    compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.11.1')
 }
```

How do i resolve please. I have encountered the issues on github [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/350) and [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-Android/issues/62) and tried the suggestions but still the same error.

Comment: firstly change compile with implementation..

Comment: Hello i have changed the compile to implementation and provided to compileOnly as shown in the updated gradle code but still the same errors @ShivamOberoi

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue while using the code given in the tutorials. To fix this issue I tried downloading the same app from their github repository, please find it's link [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android).

I think they are updating their repository but code in the tutorials is not upto date. I hope this will help someone who is looking for the solution to this problem.